# how to copy files that have a certain substring in windows

Tags: windows, linux

I have splitted text files into parts and the parts that belong to a file is ended as part1,part2 ,... partn

I want to copy only part 03 files to another folder.

I would like to do it in windows but if its easier to do it in linux then ok, i have access to a linux virtual machine as well.

Note:- there is a space between part and 03

Comment: Take a look at cygwin if you want to able to use the Unix-style command line utilities under Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
copy *part3 d:\some\other\place
```

Comment: @klijo FYI: This is the Windows command.

Comment: hi there is a space between the 3 and part. How can i handle them ?

Comment: Use quotes around the space.

Comment: i did this -> copy *"part 03" d:\test
but it didnt work, next i tried doing copy *"part" d:\test. still it didnt work.

Comment: ok this command worked copy * "part 03" * d:\test

Answer (score 0):

This is the linux equivalent:

```
cp *part3 /d/some/other/place
```